# How to run Ocaml simulations

Tags: ocaml

If I want to run a simulation of the abstract machine on the code below, how do I know what would be in the workspace, stack, and heap?

```
let rec map (f: 'a -> 'b) (y: 'a list): 'b list = 
  begin match y with
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> (f h) :: (map f t)
end in
let x = map (fun t -> t + 1) [0; 1; 2] in 
0 :: x
```

Comment: Are you looking for an equivalent of http://pythontutor.com/ for OCaml?

Answer (score 0):

You're using terminology that we (people reading StackOverflow) don't share. In particular, we don't know what abstract machine you're talking about.

Speaking very generally about computer systems, the workspace usually contains the current definitions. At the beginning it might contain predefined functions and so on. Your code uses some predefined type names (like `'a list`) and constructors (like `::`). I don't know if they need to be in your workspace specifically.

Very possibly your definitions of `map` and `x` would need to be loaded into the workspace as the first step.

The stack contains a record of the functions that have been called but haven't returned. In general it will be empty when you start an evaluation.

The heap is a general term for the set of values that exist at the moment but might disappear later (when no longer needed). Unless you count your values named `map` and `x`, the heap could also be empty at the beginning.

Sorry I can't be more specific. It sounds like you're taking a class, and you might want to consult  some of the class resources (including the professor or TA :-)